# CSS Grid Repeat Grid Layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I am creating a repeating grid system, in which I need to repeat the same structure as the first 7 items. Divs A to G is generating the result I want and all other div are coming on right position column wise but only H and M (The first and sixth item in new row and) not taking the desired height.

H need to equal to height of I and J combine and M need to be equal to K and L's combine height, same as A and F:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, [col] 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, [row] auto);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box:nth-of-type(7n+1) {
  grid-column: col / span 2;
}

.box:nth-of-type(7n+3) {
  grid-column: col 3 / span 1;
}

.box:nth-of-type(7n+4),
.box:nth-of-type(7n+5) {
  grid-column: col 1 / span 1;
}

.box:nth-child(7n+6) {
  grid-column: col 2 / span 2;
}

.box:nth-child(7n+7) {
  grid-column: col 1 / span 3;
}

.box:first-child {
  grid-row: row / span 2;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: row;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: row 2;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: row 3;
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: row 4;
}

.box:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: row 3 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
  <div class="box">G</div>

  <!--   items with same spans need to be repeted  -->
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
  <div class="box">J</div>
  <div class="box">K</div>
  <div class="box">L</div>
  <div class="box">M</div>
  <div class="box">N</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I simplified your code:

- using only the *nth-child* logic for the row-column sizing,
- removed `grid-template-rows` and the naming of the grid lines,

The issue we have now is that the boxes `E` and `F` are out of place from the rows:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /* grid-template-rows: repeat(10, [row] auto); */
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box:nth-of-type(7n+1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.box:nth-child(7n+6) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.box:nth-child(7n+7) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
  <div class="box">G</div>

  <!--   items with same spans need to be repeted  -->
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
  <div class="box">J</div>
  <div class="box">K</div>
  <div class="box">L</div>
  <div class="box">M</div>
  <div class="box">N</div>
</div>
```

Now you can shift the `F` to the last two columns using `grid-column: 2 / 4` and then use `grid-auto-flow: dense` to pull it up - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /*grid-template-rows: repeat(10, [row] auto);*/
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* fills in the spaces */
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box:nth-of-type(7n+1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.box:nth-of-type(7n+5) {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.box:nth-child(7n+6) {
  grid-column: 2 / 4; /* changed */
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.box:nth-child(7n+7) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
  <div class="box">F</div>
  <div class="box">G</div>
  <!--   items with same spans need to be repeted  -->
  <div class="box">H</div>
  <div class="box">I</div>
  <div class="box">J</div>
  <div class="box">K</div>
  <div class="box">L</div>
  <div class="box">M</div>
  <div class="box">N</div>
</div>
```